# Meteor/React: Your app is crashing but fixed error?

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I keep getting this error below but when I update the Resolutions.graphql file to correct the typo, I still get the error.

Tried restarting the Meteor server but still receiving the error.

Anything I'm missing?

```
Error: Unknown type "Sting". Did you mean "String"?
    at assertValidSDL (/Users/macos/apollo/node_modules/graphql/validation/validate.js:89:11)
    at Object.buildASTSchema (/Users/macos/apollo/node_modules/graphql/utilities/buildASTSchema.js:76:34)
    at Object.buildSchemaFromTypeDefinitions (/Users/macos/apollo/node_modules/graphql-tools/dist/generate/buildSchemaFromTypeDefinitions.js:23:28)
    at makeExecutableSchema (/Users/macos/apollo/node_modules/graphql-tools/dist/makeExecutableSchema.js:26:29)
    at register-api.js (imports/startup/server/register-api.js:22:16)
    at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:336:7)
    at Module.require (packages/modules-runtime.js:238:14)
    at Module.moduleLink [as link] (/Users/macos/.meteor/packages/modules/.0.13.0.1pfv79d.ujmak++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/reify/lib/runtime/index.js:38:38)
    at index.js (imports/startup/server/index.js:1:8)
    at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:336:7)
    at Module.require (packages/modules-runtime.js:238:14)
    at Module.moduleLink [as link] (/Users/macos/.meteor/packages/modules/.0.13.0.1pfv79d.ujmak++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/reify/lib/runtime/index.js:38:38)
    at init.js (server/init.js:1:8)
    at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:336:7)
    at Module.require (packages/modules-runtime.js:238:14)
    at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:258:21)
Exited with code: 1
Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

Resolutions.graphql:

```
type Resolutions {
  _id: String!
  name: String!
}
```

Comment: Do you have `Sting` anywhere in your own code?

Comment: nope that was the only place with the type. Checked all the other files :(

Comment: Would there be a caching issue maybe with Meteor or something related?

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it to work using **meteor reset** instead of just cmd + c and then **meteor**